# Display icon at google place marker.title

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to make an android application to display restaurants nearby to user.
I have a google map display and add markers with the restaurants. When user tap a marker, it show up info. Title of restaurant,  rating and Icon if exist.
Im using [Place search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?hl=el) and i'm get the information for each restaurant. 
Its work but when I'm trying to display the icon it show up null.

Hear is the code that im trying to get the image of reaturant

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) 
        throws IOException
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            int response = -1;

            URL url = new URL(urlString); 
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
                throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

            try{
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect(); 

                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
                }                     
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
            }
            return in;     
        }

private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
{        
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;        
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;                
}
```

and to display it

```
//Getting icon
            String iconURL = hmPlace.get("iconURL");
            Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(iconURL);
markerOptions.title(name + " : " + bitmap );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MarkerOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html).title takes a string as the argument, so you can't append a Bitmap file to it.

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) for adding marker's to the maps. To show an image, you are going to need to set a custom InfoWindow using a custom [InfoWindowAdapter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter).